# Running Multiple domains in Nginx on Single IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to handle multiple websites in a single IP address using Nginx.

##### Root Website: (/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name test.com;

ssl_certificate path_to_crt;
ssl_certificate_key path_to_pem;



location / {
        root /var/www/html/app/build;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8004/;
        }
}
```

##### Sub-Website1: (/etc/nginx/sites-available/one.test.com)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name one.test.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name one.test.com;

ssl_certificate path_to_crt;
ssl_certificate_key path_to_pem;



location / {
        root /var/www/html/app1/build;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003/;
        }
}
```

##### Sub-Website 2: (/etc/nginx/sites-available/two.test.com)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name two.test.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name two.test.com;

ssl_certificate path_to_crt;
ssl_certificate_key path_to_pem;



location / {
        root /var/www/html/app2/build;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8005/;
        }
}
```

#### Scenario:

1. Root Website is working properly.
2. Sub-Website1 is working properly.
3. When hitting Sub-Website2, it is hitting Sub-Website1. (Issue).

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Check that the `server` blocks are all present. Did you remember the `sites-enabled` symlink?